# Unable to Open base64 decoded '.jpg' image due to 'Source Missing'?

Tags: python, django, image, base64

I am trying to send a `.jpg` file using `request` and trying to decode it in 
django server side.

**CODE:**

This is the sending side code:

```
import requests
import os
import base64
fPath = os.getcwd()
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/submitcausedata/'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
path_img = fPath + '/image13.jpg'
data = open(path_img,'rb').read()
encoded_image = base64.encodestring(data)   
print(encoded_image[:10])
r = requests.post(url,data=encoded_image,headers=headers)
```

On receiving end Code:

```
@csrf_exempt
def submitCauseData(request):   
    response_data = {}  
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST     
        myDict = dict(data)     
        imageStr = list(myDict.keys())      
        imageStr = imageStr[0]
        print(imageStr[:10])
        image_result = open('image.jpg', 'wb')       
        image_result.write(base64.b64decode(imageStr))
        return HttpResponse("Page Exists")
```

So, the code is executing but when I try to Open the saved Image it shows the error `Photo Source File missing`?

The sending code output of:

```
print(encoded_image[:10])
----> b'/9j/4WQYRX'
```

The receiving side code output of:

```
print(imageStr[:10])
----> /9j/4WQYRX
```

**UPDATE:**

While comparing both the `.jpg` files using `.txt` conversion a lot of values in both of them are different using `DiffChecker` Online.

The Image Viewer on Ubuntu shows the Error while opening the `.jpg` on receiving side:

```
Error interpreting JPEG image file (Unsupported marker type 0x10)
```

Also:

On Sending Side:

```
print(len(data))
print(type(data))
print(len(encoded_image))
print(type(encoded_image))

OUTPUT:

171062
<class 'bytes'>
228084
<class 'bytes'>
```

On receiving side:

```
print(len(imageStr))
print(type(imageStr))
print(len(imagedec))
print(type(imagedec))

OUTPUT:

228083
<class 'str'>
168972
<class 'bytes'>
```

Comment: What do you mean "when I try to Open the saved Image", where are you trying to open it?

Comment: I am trying to open it using Shotwell Photo Viewer In Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: When I am trying to encode and decode the image on the sending side it works fine and opens the image correctly but when I try decoding on recieving side it doesn't.

Comment: The encoding and decoding looks fine, although what you are doing with `imageStr` and the dictionary may not be. What is the output of `ImageStr[0]`? If you paste the base64 string in a browser what do you get?

Comment: imageStr is a single element list ,and imageStr[0] has the same content as the encoded image content.

Comment: So you know the encoding/decoding part is working; it sounds like your photo viewer isn't opening the right image or something else.

Comment: The same photo viewer is opening the image after decoding if done on sending side.

Comment: If you can post the original file and the one that gets generated somewhere so we can compare them.

Comment: Please see the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error as when I am trying to send the `class` of `byte` string from sending side, what happens is all the `'+'` and `'='` get converted to `' '` on receiving side.

So, by using:

Sending Side:

```
import requests
import os
import base64
fPath = os.getcwd()
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/submitcausedata/'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
path_img = fPath + '/image13.jpg'
data = open(path_img,'rb').read()
encoded_image = base64.b64encode(data)  
r = requests.post(url,data=encoded_image,headers=headers)
```

Receiving Side:

```
@csrf_exempt
def submitCauseData(request):   
    response_data = {}      
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST     
        myDict = dict(data)     
        imageStr = list(myDict.keys())      
        image = imageStr[0].replace(' ','+')
        image = image.encode() + b'==='                             
        imagedec = base64.b64decode(image)
        fPath = os.getcwd()     
        image_result = open(fPath + '/image.jpg', 'wb')
        image_result.write(imagedec)
        image_result.close()            
        return HttpResponse("HELLO")
```

I solved the error.

Anyways, thanks for the help `@waket-zheng` :)

Answer (score 0):

Does the following code work?

sending

```
from base64 import b64encode
from pathlib import Path

import requests


url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/submitcausedata/"
headers = {"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
encoded_image = b64encode(Path("image13.jpg").read_bytes())
print(encoded_image[:10])
r = requests.post(url, data=encoded_image, headers=headers)
```

receiving

```
from base64 import b64decode
from pathlib import Path    

@csrf_exempt
def submitCauseData(request):
    response_data = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        imageStr = list(dict(request.POST).keys())[0]
        print(imageStr[:10])
        p = Path("image.jpg")
        p.write_bytes(b64decode(imageStr))
        return HttpResponse(f"Saved image to `{p.resolve()}`")
```

Comment: Alas, the same error still exists, I think the error is due to them being of different `class` type and due to `URL` encoding of `+` and `=` has given me error of `binascii.Error: Incorrect padding`

Comment: I am trying something in the direction of `imageStr = imageStr[0].encode() + b'='`